# java string vs mysql string

Tags: java, mysql, string, character-encoding

```
mysql> CREATE database testing CHARACTER SET utf16;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE testing;
Database changed

mysql> CREATE TABLE t (str varchar(64));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

mysql> INSET INTO t values ("1234567891234567");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

=============================

Then I have a piece of java code

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pass);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

statement.execute("USE  testing");

ResultSet rst = statement.executeQuery("SELECT str, LENGTH(str) FROM t;");
while (rst.next())
             System.out.print("java length: " + rst.getString(1).length() 
                     + "\nmysql length: " + rst.getInt(2));
```

This would give

```
java length: 16
mysql length: 32
```

I dont understand why the lengths are different. I explicitly set the database's character set to UTF16 (which is the default charset of Java, right?) Why do I still get inconsistent length values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mySql function "CHAR_LENGTH()" returns the #/Unicode characters (like Java's ".length").

The MySQL function "LENGTH()" returns the #/bytes.

Here's the MySQL reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

Mysql [LENGTH(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

> Returns the length of the string `str`, measured in bytes. A multi-byte
>   character counts as multiple bytes. This means that for a string
>   containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10, whereas
>   CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

Maybe what you need is [CHAR_LENGTH(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

> Returns the length of the string `str`, measured in characters. A
>   multi-byte character counts as a single character. This means that for
>   a string containing five two-byte characters, LENGTH() returns 10,
>   whereas CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

Default charset of Java is not UTF-16, its locale [dependent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29).

If you want to change Charset in Java then you will have to do it before JVM startup, or else value of defaultCharset which is locale dependent will be used.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect in UTF-16 encoding:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url+"?characterEncoding=UTF-16", usr, pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Java ios reporting the number of characters, while MySQL is reporting the number of bytes used to store the characters.